# Setting up environment variable for checker framework

Tags: java, environment-variables

I want to use checker framework for java and I am setting environment variable for it but when I am checking version of it in PowerShell in windows. It is showing that it is not able to access checker framework.

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:%CHECKERS%/binary/jsr308-all.jar -jar %CHECKERS%/binary/jsr308-all.jar -version
```

Here is the error

> Error: Unable to access jarfile %CHECKERS%/binary/jsr308-all.jar

I have unzipped the downloaded file in C drive. And for the environment variable here is the paths that i have tried.

**1**

> C:\checker-framework-2.7.0\checker-framework-2.7.0\checker\di

**2**

> C:\checker-framework\checkers

**3**

> C:\checker-framework-2.7.0\checker-framework-2.7.0\checker

**4**

> C:\checker-framework-2.7.0\checker-framework-2.7.0

Comment: Your shell is not expanding %CHECKERS% to a value.  Try writing the command using an explicit path rather than "%CHECKERS".

Answer (score 0):

environmental variables are accessed using $env:env_veriable in PowerShell.

example:  **$env:JAVA_HOME**

for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6

Comment: but, i don't want to know the value of the environment variable.